# Powers of 10 generator (Cannot find variable i)

Tags: java

I am working on the "Powers of" generator and I get an error that variable i cannot be found. I clearly declared it in the for loop

```
    public class EP63
{

    private static int answer;
    public static int PowerGenerator(double aFactor)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++);
        {
            answer = Math.pow(aFactor,i); 
            nextPower();

            return answer;

        }
    }   

    public static double nextPower()
    {
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem?

Comment: How come everyone is voting down for this post? I have been looking for help for 30min!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++);
```

Change to:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
```

The body of the for loop is a single expression. `;` is interpreted as an no-op expression, so the `{ }` block is not part of the loop, therefore `i` is not defined there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a ; after the for loop.

That means the for loop have only 1 empty statement.
i.e. your code is just the same as

```
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
  // nothing
}

{
  answer = Math.pow(aFactor,i); 
  nextPower();
  return answer;
}
```